# Two interfaces connected to the same subnet, how to prioritise one?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

On the following system, I have a networking problem, yet I am not a networking expert.

```
CentOS release 5.4 (Final) Linux localhost.localdomain
2.6.18-164.6.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Nov 3 16:12:36 EST 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Both ethernet interfaces are configured to connect to the same subnet, which does not seem ideal to me and I think was done as a previous workaround for a fault. The effect is that ifconfig looks like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:03:2D:10:76:B0
          inet addr:192.168.168.3  Bcast:192.168.168.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::203:2dff:fe10:76b0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3084 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:1422781 (1.3 MiB)  TX bytes:1695768 (1.6 MiB)
          Memory:fdfc0000-fdfe0000

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:03:2D:10:76:B1
          inet addr:192.168.168.122  Bcast:192.168.168.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::203:2dff:fe10:76b1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:35 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:4236 (4.1 KiB)  TX bytes:12980 (12.6 KiB)
          Memory:fdec0000-fdee0000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:252097 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:252097 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:85617560 (81.6 MiB)  TX bytes:85617560 (81.6 MiB)
```

And route list:

```
192.168.168.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.168.3
192.168.168.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.168.122
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link 
default via 192.168.168.1 dev eth0 
default via 192.168.168.1 dev eth1
```

Sending traffic over eth0 to 192.168.168.x does not work, but this route is chosen in preference to the one over eth1, which does. I figured out how to correct the situation, by running

```
/sbin/ip route del 192.168.168.0/24 dev eth0
```

However, this configuration is removed when the server restarts, (and at other times...?).

I know I'll likely get quite some comments and answers to the effect that I should be resolving the underlying connectivity issue, such that the interfaces are not connecting to the same subnet, or only one is used, and I would agree! However, the machine is in a very remote part of the world and actually changing the physical networking and its connectivity to the rest of the network is hard as local IT personnel cannot help and this situation exists because of faults elsewhere in the network beyond my control.

Thanks!

Comment: No time for a full answer, but take a look at the 'metric' options for NICs/routes.

Comment: Thanks @mtak, I actually tried this, by setting METRIC=100 in the ifcfg-eth1 configuration file. This was then only applied to the default route, not to the specific 192.168.168.x route. Is there a way to configure it specifically for the direct route?

Comment: What are the two interfaces connected to, physically? The same LAN? Is there a DHCP server on the LANs?

Comment: I believe they are connected to the same router, a historic attempt to work around a different problem. eth0 is configured statically, eth1 is configured via DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a working solution by removing the default route via eth0 I would suggest that you remove it from it's static configuration.

Most likely this is configured in this file */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0*. Open it with an editor and comment out or remove the row containing *GATEWAY=192.168.168.1*.

To apply the configuration I would suggest that you take down the interface and then take it up, this is to avoid reloading all network devices. Here's the commands for that.

```
ip link set dev eth0 down
ip link set dev eth0 up
```

Further doccumentation about the ifcfg file can be found [here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html).